# Plot bar chart from nested dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot a bar chart from a nested dictionary such as this?

```
{
    Weekly: {
        'Gas': '65.22',
        'Electricity': '120.01'
     },
     Monthly: {
         'Gas': '171.05',
         'Electricity': '252.12'
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this site: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/BarCharts you will find a good tutorial, how to create bar charts in matplotlib. If your dictionary is stored in the variable `d` you can access the list of labels with:

```
labels = d.keys() # ['Monthly', 'Weekly']
```

For the values you can use:

```
gas = [ float(x['Gas']) for x in d.values() ] # [171.05, 65.22]
electricity = [ float(x['Electricity']) for x in d.values() ] # [171.05, 65.22]
```